# How to Implement embarrassingly parallel task (FOR loop) WITHOUT MPI-IO?

Tags: mpi, openmp, communication

**Preamble**:

I have a very large array (one dim) and need to solve evolution equation (wave-like eq). I I need to calculate integral at each value of this array, to store the resulting array of integral and apply integration again to this array, and so on (in simple words, I apply integral on grid of values, store this new grid, apply integration again and so on).

I used MPI-IO to spread over all nodes: there is a shared .dat file on my disc, each MPI copy reads this file (as a source for integration), performs integration and writes again to this shared file. This procedure repeats again and again. It works fine. The most time consuming part was the integration and file reading-writing was negligible.

**Current problem**:

Now I moved to **1024** (16x64 CPU) HPC cluster and now I'm facing an opposite problem: a calculation time is NEGLIGIBLE to read-write process!!!

I tried to reduce a number of MPI processes: I use only 16 MPI process (to spread over the nodes) + 64 threads with OpenMP to parallelize my computation inside of each node.

Again, reading and writing processes is the most time consuming part now.

**Question**

How should I modify my program, in order to utilize the full power of 1024 CPUs with minimal loss?

The important point, is that I cannot move to the next step without completing the entire 1D array.

**My thoughts:**

Instead of reading-writing, I can ask my rank=0 (master rank) to send-receive the entire array to all nodes (MPI_Bcast). So, instead of each node will I/O, only one node will do it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think I am confused.  It sounds like you are reading and writing to disk after each iteration, and using the reads and writes to share your data among all processors.  But with MPI (even without MPI-IO) there are much more efficient ways to share the data.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yes, you are Right! After one iteration (the full matrix) is completed, I write (each MPI procs. writes its part) to disc (the shared file). The second iteration starts with reading this file (this matrix is used as an initial value for the next iteration), stores in array (which is local to each MPI procs), performs computation and writes again to (new) shared file on disc. And so on.

Comment: There is also another reason for using read/write to disc (the computations may be terminated unexpectedly due to some reasons) and I prefer to store the last step (in evolution) on my local disc in order to start again the evolution from this step.

Comment: What is the best way to share a data array among all MPI procs?

Comment: See links in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would look [here](http://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=MPI+wave+equation+1d+example&oq=MPI+wave+equation+1d+example&gs_l=hp.3..33i21l2.416.10040.0.10152.38.33.4.1.1.0.222.4428.1j28j3.32.0...1.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.V0ukBTfkLN4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46226182,d.cGE&fp=554c6b35d48128d0&biw=1085&bih=841) and [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#ExamplesWave).  FORTRAN code for the second site is [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/Fortran/mpi_wave.f) and C code is [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_wave.c).

The idea is that you *don't* give the entire array to each processor.  You give each processor only the piece it works on, with some overlap between processors so they can handle their mutual boundaries.

Also, you are right to save your computation to disk every so often.  And I like MPI-IO for that.  I think it is the way to go.  But the codes in the links will allow you to run without reading every time.  And, for my money, writing out the data *every single time* is overkill.

Comment: One more thing: I'm actually pretty impressed that you were able to tackle MPI-IO without knowing some of the more basic stuff of MPI.  I would say you are probably going to do well with this project.